# Extract 3 tables from the source table by specific text in cell

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a source table with more or less this format :

[image: source_table]

And I search how to extract the data for each section by using only the data from 'Name' column.
But like i'm pretty new to PowerQuery and PowerBi, I don't find the right command to reach my goal

The first possibillity is to add a new column and identify each line by the title like this :

[image: Solution 1]

Or the second possibility is to create 3 new table for each title and separate the data like this :

[image: Solution 2]

Thanks

Comment: Do the titles always contain underscores?

Comment: nop, it's just an example, you need to read free text instead

Comment: @horseyride has got it. That is the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Add a custom column that checks the Value1 column for a null, and if its a null, then return the value in Name

```
= if [Value 1]=null then [Name] else null
```

then right click and fill down that new column, and apply a filter to it

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each if [Value 1]=null then [Name] else null),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"})
// add row here to optionally filter on Custom column
in  #"Filled Down"
```

Or just have one query and create more queries that have specific filters like this one

```
let Source  = Table.SelectRows(OtherQueryNameHere, each [Custom] = "m") in Source
```

Comment: It's a simple example, but there are also value in Value1 column, I'm looking to manage it by using only the name column

Comment: Then find something unique about the name column and use that instead of a null in the value column. Does it contain an underscore? Test for that.  Alpha in a column of numerics? Test for that. Are sections separated by a blank row? Test for that. Provide some specific here.  If you don't give us a good sample input, the recommended solution will not match the need